# Is it possible to run multiple animations on multiple views with one AnimationSet?

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

What would be a correct way of running multiple animations at same time as a single animation? This can be done by AnimatorSet but I am wondering if the same is possible with AnimationSet.

Comment: you dont need AnimatorSet for that, simple ObjectAnimator / ValueAnimator will be ok

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know best option for running multiple animations on a view is using PropertyValuesHolder which you can use it simply by .animate() method on the view

```
theView.animate().setDuration(100).rotation(34).translationX(100).start();
```

the advantage is not just simplicity, its optimization affects of performance too.

Comment: but what if I have two views? I would like to animate them with a single start() call.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two views

**First**: create the animation: `Animation animation =  ...`

**Second**: start this animation: `your_View.startAnimation(animation )`

**Final**: Use AnimationListener

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        your_another_View.startAnimation(animation )
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    }
});
```